# Combinatorial interpretation of identity for stirling number of second kind

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to find a combinatorial interpretation for the following identity

$$S(n+1, m+1)=\sum_{k=m}^{n}\binom{n}{k}S(k,m)$$.

And am having a lot of trouble thinking of one. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The Stirling number of the second kind is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into a collection of $m$ subsets.

Comment: Ok, I have a different idea. The right side could represent selecting n-k balls, and putting them all into one bin, and then putting the remaining k balls into m other bins, and we sum of the size of k. The only problem with this is the n+1 on the left side.

Edit: ah, now if we first place one ball in a bin, there's only one way to do that, so it's 1 times the summation.